# Monotouch 'mtouch failed with no output (137)' after updating to Apple SDK 4.3

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I updated to iPhone SDK 4.3 today and now it's not possible to build/run (in debug or release mode) any of my projects that worked fine in iPhone SDK 4.2.

When I try to build or run Monodevelop "hangs" on "Compiling to native code"

If I try to run/debug to the `iPhoneSimulator` I get the error message:

> "Error merging info.plist: Invalid
>   data"

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I'm having the same problem. I have SDK 4.3, Mono framework 2.10.1, MonoTouch 4.0.0, and MonoDevelop 2.4.2. My debugger had lost the ability to hit breakpoints, so I had removed Mono, MonoTouch, and MonoDevelop, and then re-installed. Was able to hit breakpoints on first build, but then cleaned the solution and got the same error message when I rebuilt: "Error merging info.plist: Invalid data". Other solutions build just fine. Even re-created the solution; no success. Co-worker can build from my code just fine. ANYONE??? What's fubarred here???

Comment: RESOLVED for me. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly target the 4.2 iOS SDK inside your project's options, under the iPhone Build section. When it is at the Default setting, it always targets the latest iOS version installed.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to MonoTouch 3.2.5 will resolve this issue.

For an older version, you just need to create a symlink:

```
cd /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs
sudo ln -s MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.3.sdk
```

No symlink is needed for the device SDK directory, as it does not contain a version number.

Answer (score 0):

Upates are released to both MonoDevelop and MonoTouch that fix this problem. The updates are available through the update function in MonoDevelop

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It all started for me when I uninstalled/re-installed my dev environment in order to fix something else (breakpoints not being hit during debugging).

So, even though I re-staged my entire laptop in order to come to this conclusion, user653490 is correct, the update to MonoDevelop DOES fix the problem. However, what is NOT clear at first is the fact that the BUILD VERSION is very important. Whereas I was still seeing "Error merging info.plist: Invalid data" with MonoDevelop 2.4.2 build 20402000, once I was using build 2040200***4***, I was able to compile again. The build version is the key. Hope this helps someone else, because it was very frustrating.